# Blue Origin's The New Shepard crew capsule's design

Tags: blue-origin

Generally first stage boosters are just tubes with tanks and engines attached to the later stages. However, [based on this photo](http://www.gizmag.com/jeff-bezos-blue-origin-flies-its-first-rocket/37274/pictures#3):

[image: Tapered Ring]

Blue Origin has this tapered design of the crew capsule and a ring that attaches to stage I.

Is there any benefit of this design as opposed to conventional?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, it wasn't stage 1.
Still, what is the point in the ring with space between it and the capsule?

Comment: Could you edit the question to reflect the new nature of the question, and clarify what is in the photo? Otherwise someone searching later won't know what the question is really about.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the tapered ring allows an exhaust path for the "full envelope" abort system exhaust while not compromising the size of the capsule.